# Pause Loop until click modal button

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I need enter manually some values during a loop for. I'm using C# ASP.Net with WebForms.

I'm trying this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace systemII
{
    public partial class MY_System : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        private List<String> List = new List<string>();
        private bool loop = false;

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            while (loop) { }

            for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
            {
                string a = "A" + i.ToString();
                if (i == 4 || i == 5)
                {
                    loop = true;
                    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Pop", "openModal();", true);
                }
                else
                {
                    List.Add(a);
                }
            }
        }

        protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // modal button
        {
            string b = "BB";
            Lista.Add(b);
            loop = false;
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

But the Modal appear on screen after end of loop. I need pause the loop until I enter the textbox value.

Any can help me? Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: You're currently running synchronized code. Consider using [async code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/hh191443.aspx) to  make a pause and continue button. Otherwise the loop will first complete, then will do your rest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ASP.Net you cannot just pause the server-side code since the server-side code is always executed fully (never partially) even if you use asynchronous page in ASP.Net and also, server-side is `never` connected to browser but is executed in a separate  process. Browser never knows and doesn't care what's happening on server-side, and the server-side doesn't know nor cares about what browser is doing, `so it's impossible` to connect server-side code to browser the way you want.

*However, you can simulate what you want by breaking from the loop when the first index =4 is reached and modal popup script emitted.* Then you can do a similar thing for i= 5 when user has inputted values for i=4 and page has posted back. But, the values of `i` that were successfully handled for input will need to be tracked across requests from browser, which is done in code below by setting a `ViewState` variable called `HandledValues` which is just a collection of List of string type.

**So the workflow if you use this code will be**: User will be prompted to input values for i=4  in a modal popup and then when a button `Button1` is clicked and page posts back, the user will be prompted to input values for i = 5 in a modal popup.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     //a list of values handled is stored in ViewState as ValuesHandled
     List<string> handledValues = new List<string>();
     if (ViewState["ValuesHandled"] != null) {
         List<string> handledValues =  (ViewState["ValuesHandled"] as List<string>;
     }

    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        string a = "A" + i.ToString();
        //check if i = 4 has had its values input successfully
        if (i == 4  && !handledValues.Contains(i.ToString()))
        {
            loop = true;
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Pop", "openModal();", true);
            handledValues.Add(i.toString());
            //break the loop since we need to return to browser for input by user
            break;
        }
        else if (i == 4 && handledValues.Contains(i.ToString()))
        {
         //remove handled value if no modal popup needed to be opened
         handledValues.Remove(i.ToString())
        }
        else if (i == 5  && !handledValues.Contains(i.ToString()))
        {//check if i = 5 has had its values input successfully
            loop = true;
            handledValues.Add(i.toString());
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Pop", "openModal();", true);
            //break the loop since we need to return to browser for input by user
            break;
        }
        else if (i == 5 && handledValues.Contains(i.ToString()))
        {
         //remove handled value if no modal popup needed to be opened
         handledValues.Remove(i.ToString())
        }
        else
        {
            List.Add(a);
        }
    }


    //update the ViewState for ValuesHandled
   ViewState["ValuesHandled"] = handledValues;
}
```

Comment: I have solve my problem with your help! Thanks a lot :)